# Missing field error when adding fields to autopopulate new record

Tags: custom-button

I have a custom button that I'm using on a related list from either a contact or lead. The button will auto-populate some fields for the new record before saving.

Here is the syntax I'm using for the button:

```
{!IF(Lead.Id <> "",URLFOR('https://companyname--staging1.cs61.my.salesforce.com/a3S/e', null,[CF00N4C000000zqSV=Lead.Name,CF00N4C000000zqSV_lkid=Lead.Id]),URLFOR('https://companyname--staging1.cs61.my.salesforce.com/a3S/e',null, [CF00N4C00000104EI=Contact.Name,CF00N4C00000104EI_lkid=Contact.Id]))}
```

The above code works for the fields I have included. As soon as I add another field to auto-populate, I get this error:

> Syntax error. Missing field name

Here is the code with the added field name:

```
{!IF(Lead.Id  <> "",URLFOR('https://companyname--staging1.cs61.my.salesforce.com/a3S/e', null,[CF00N4C000000zqSV=Lead.Name,CF00N4C000000zqSV_lkid=Lead.Id,00N4C000000zpTm=Lead.Name]),URLFOR('https://companyname--staging1.cs61.my.salesforce.com/a3S/e',null, [CF00N4C00000104EI=Contact.Name,CF00N4C00000104EI_lkid=Contact.Id,00N4C000000zpTm=Lead.Name]))}
```

Comment: system could not find this field 00N4C000000zpTm

Comment: I've checked and re-checked using Firebug. That is the value of the id and name attribute of the input  field.

Comment: Are you aware that you will never come across a saved `Lead` record whose `Id` is blank?

Comment: Rewire your logic as per Adrian's advice, Lead has first and last name fields and the Ids for both are listed here you can inspect/ use firebug to find the same http://theblogreaders.com/salesforce-standard-object-field-ids/#.V1a0Vtl97Dc